# Extruding a graph in three.js

Tags: 3d, geometry, three.js

Is there a way to extrude a 2D graph that's in 3D space to a 3D geometry with actual volume?

Specifically, I'm trying to create a simple app to play with shapes for my 3D printer (I know there are other well known programs out there, but I'd like to try this myself). I've modified one of the tutorials by @LeeStemkoski (which are awesome by the way... if you're reading this, thank you!) to create a Mobius Strip grapher [here](http://www.jonoshaughnessy.org/sandbox/mobius_shape_generator.html%22). It has no volume and obviously can't be printed. I'd like to turn that into a geometry with actual volume (a watertight mesh).

I've looked at 2D extrusion examples like [these](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_splines.html). None seem to address what I'm attempting to do. The spline example comes close but I don't know enough to know if it's possible to adapt it to my purposes. I'm trying to tinker with the examples and look at the supporting docs/libraries, but I'm having a lot of difficulty with this.

Is this possible in three.js or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Maybe sharing a sketch of what you're trying to achieve would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks MrDoob. I realized I was going about this the wrong way. I was trying to take a graphed function and give it volume which I now know is very odd (versus simply creating a real geometry). Thanks for the help!