# Smoothly joining multiple cylinders / tubes in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js

I'm laying out a network of blood vessels in Three.js. For this I've found [`THREE.TubeGeometry`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/TubeGeometry) very useful. But I obviously can't form a branching network out of one tube. I need to join multiple tubes together. Here's an example:

[image: (left) bad join, (right) smooth bend]

On the left you see a point where multiple tubes join. In terms of Bézier curves, the three control points and the join-point are perfectly co-linear here. Still, it's obviously an ugly join. In contrast, look at the bend in the curve on the right side, created internally by `TubeGeometry`. I'd like my manual joins to be smooth like that.

It seems to be a bad alignment of cross-sections, which are not perfect circles, but 8-segment polygons. Indeed, if I increase the number of segments, the disparity becomes less noticeable, but this brings with it a big performance hit. And really, 8 segments is plenty. I think I just need to adjust their rotation to match, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Related post with alternate approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738386/how-to-create-a-three-js-3d-line-series-with-width-and-thickness.  Also http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/05/webgl-rendering-of-solid-trails/.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think this addresses my issue. Both links reject Three.js `TubeGeometry` for one reason or another, and are trying to create it in some fundamentally new way. I'm basically fine with how `TubeGeometry` works, and my implementation is basically finished, except for this small detail. I don't think switching to a fundamentally different approach is the answer for me. :-)

Comment: Fair enough. I am not sure you will find a solution to your question, so I provided alternatives. The only other idea I could suggest is to extend your cylinders at each end a bit so they overlap at the junctions.

Comment: I get it. And that second link was still interesting. I think I will dive into the `TubeGeometry` code at some point to find the answer, possibly fork my own version of it.