# Threejs edge helper

Tags: three.js

I'm new to Threejs and I have been using the EdgesHelper which achieves the look I want for now. But I have two questions...

1. What is the default edge width/how is it calculated?
2. Can the edge width be changed...

I have searched around and I'm pretty sure that due to some limitation (not of threejs of Windows I believe) that there is no simple method to change the thickness of the edges (?).  Alot of the examples I found that have thicker edges would only work on a particular geometry (e.g. doesn't seem universal).

Perhaps I am wrong but I would have thought that this would be a very common requirement? Rather then spend hours/days/weeks trying to get what i want myself (which I'm not even sure I personally would be able to do), does anyone know of a way to have control over the edge thickness, an existing example or a library that someone has already done that can work on any shape (any imported obj for example)

Many thanks

Comment: You will find your answers in [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11638883/1697459) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26709144/1697459) is probably also interesting for you. [Google](https://www.google.se/search?q=three+js+line+width) will give you even more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back to this as Wilt mentioned there are other threads on this.  Basically you cannot change the thickness due to a limitation in ANGLE, there are some work around like the THREE.MeshLine (also mentioned in the link Wilt stated) but i found most work aroudns had some limitations for what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

https://mattdesl.svbtle.com/drawing-lines-is-hard explains what is difficult to it in lines.

He also has a library called https://github.com/mattdesl/three-line-2d which should make lines easier to use.