# How to increase line thickness in three.js edges geometry using shaders?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm trying to replicate the effect shown in [this](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_wireframe) Three.js example but instead of showing the wireframe and an opaque box, I'd like to show just the edges without any faces (like what is shown when using the [THREE.EdgesGeometry](http://jsfiddle.net/SZR_Harrison/6k2y95am/).) I know that setting the `linewidth` property doesn't work and that using shaders is necessary but I'm not really sure where to begin. For reference, these are the shaders being used in the above Three.js example:

Vertex Shader:

```
attribute vec3 center;
varying vec3 vCenter;

void main() {
    vCenter = center;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
varying vec3 vCenter;

float edgeFactorTri() {
    vec3 d = fwidth( vCenter.xyz );
    vec3 a3 = smoothstep( vec3( 0.0 ), d * 1.5, vCenter.xyz );
    return min( min( a3.x, a3.y ), a3.z );
}

void main() {

    gl_FragColor.rgb = mix( vec3( 1.0 ), vec3( 0.2 ), edgeFactorTri() );
    gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
}
```

I've gotten as far as figuring out that changing what `d` gets multiplied by (1.5 in the example) is what determines the thickness of the line but I'm completely lost as to how the `vCenter` variable is actually used (it's a `vec3` that is either `[1, 0, 0]`, `[0, 1, 0]` or `[0, 0, 1]`) or what I could use to make the THREE.EdgesGeometry render with thicker lines like in the example.

Here is what happens when I try rendering the edges geometry with these shaders:

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
            attribute vec3 center;
            varying vec3 vCenter;

            void main() {
                vCenter = center;
                gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

            }
</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShader">
            varying vec3 vCenter;
            uniform float lineWidth;

            float edgeFactorTri() {
                float newWidth = lineWidth + 0.5;
                vec3 d = fwidth( vCenter.xyz );
                vec3 a3 = smoothstep( vec3( 0.0 ), d * newWidth, vCenter.xyz );
                return min( min( a3.x, a3.y ), a3.z );
            }

            void main() {

                gl_FragColor.rgb = mix( vec3( 1.0 ), vec3( 0.2 ), edgeFactorTri() );
                gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
            }
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
size = 150
geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(size, size, size);
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ wireframe: true });

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.position.x = -150;
scene.add(mesh);

//

// geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(new THREE.BoxGeometry(size, size, size));
geometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(new THREE.BoxGeometry(size, size, size));
setupAttributes(geometry);

material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: { lineWidth: { value: 10 } },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById("vertexShader").textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById("fragmentShader").textContent
});

material.extensions.derivatives = true;
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.position.x = 150;
scene.add(mesh);

//

geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(new THREE.SphereGeometry(size / 2, 32, 16));

setupAttributes(geometry);

material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: { lineWidth: { value: 1 } },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById("vertexShader").textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById("fragmentShader").textContent
});

material.extensions.derivatives = true;

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.position.x = -150;
scene.add(mesh);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SZR_Harrison/vy0we5wb/)

As you can see in the fiddle, this is not what I'm looking for, but I don't have a good enough grasp on how the shaders work to know where I'm going wrong or if this approach would work for what I want.

I've looked into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26709144) but I'm not sure how to use it as a `ShaderMaterial` and I can't use it as a shader pass ([here](https://webgl-lab.herokuapp.com/js/shaders/ThickLineShader.js) are the shaders he uses for his answer.)

I've also looked into [THREE.MeshLine](https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine) and [this issue](https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine/issues/37) doesn't seem to have been resolved.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this acceptable? http://jsfiddle.net/vy0we5wb/4/. There is also [this related PR](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/11349).

Comment: plus 1 on the PR  minus 1 for not having it on npm :)

Comment: @pailhead we're waiting for r91! :)

Comment: wow look at that didnt see the milestone :D

Comment: @WestLangley That jsFiddle will probably work for what I need. More excited about the PR though! I'll probably play with your work there to see if I can achieve that effect with `THREE.EdgesGeometry`. If you want to write an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @s.z.r.harrison The technique only works with geometries that represent triangle meshes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to modify [this](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_wireframe.html) three.js example so the mesh is rendered as a thick wireframe.

The solution is to modify the shader and discard fragments in the center portion of each face -- that is, discard fragments not close to an edge.

You can do that like so:

```
void main() {

    float factor = edgeFactorTri();
    if ( factor > 0.8 ) discard; // cutoff value is somewhat arbitrary
    gl_FragColor.rgb = mix( vec3( 1.0 ), vec3( 0.2 ), factor );
    gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
}
```

You can also set `material.side = THREE.DoubleSide` if you want.

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vy0we5wb/4.

three.js r.89